# How to address an exact element (from multiple ones with the same class) on the related checkbox action?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a small table-like widget that has multiple stripes (`<div class="widget_stripe">`) in it, each of which have a name (title) and a checkbox. The HTML structure is as follows:

```
<div class="widget_stripe">
    <div class="col-sm-10 activity_name_holder">
        <p class="activity_name">Send the annual report to Mr. Smith</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 status_checkboxes_holder">
         <form action="#" class="allow_mediacontacts_form">
              <p>
                 <input class="t3t" type="checkbox" id="activity8" />
                 <label class="l3l" for="activity8"></label>
              </p>
         </form>
     </div>
</div>
```

So what I want to do is to change the font-weight (from 700 to 400) of the text inside `<p class="activity_name>`, so I'm adding a special class when the checkbox is checked.

```
var activityName = $('p.activity_name');
$("input.t3t").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(activityName).addClass('checked_name');
    } else {
        $(activityName).removeClass('checked_name');
    }
});
```

However, as you can see, it will simply fire this action an all the `<p>`s with this class, and I **cannot** figure out how to address that exact `<p class="activity_name>` that is situated in the same `<div class="widget_stripe">` that the checkbox. How can I achieve this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this and navigation to apply the class only to the selected item

```
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
  $(this).closest("div.widget_stripe").find("p.activity_name").addClass('checked_name');
} else {
  $(this).closest("div.widget_stripe").find("p.activity_name").removeClass('checked_name');
}
```

Comment: You can use [toggleClass with a boolean](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-className-state) to add or remove a class based on a condition.